# Request or AccessManager QT

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

In **Google Chrome**, when an error occurs in the request to the server, the **Google Chrome** tries a new request, see LOG *wireshark*:
[image: wireshark log]

> Note: This second attempt also ocorrre in Firefox and InternetExplorer.
>   Note: WebInspector only appears in a request, in other words: The conventional browsers try new requests within a number of times or within a time.

I'm developing a full browser in `QT`
and realized that if a request fails the **"QWebView"** has the same behavior as **Google Chrome**.

How can I reimplement the `QNetWorkRequest/QNetWorkAccessManager` to work like the conventional browsers?

Help me please.

```
myWebPage *myWP = new myWebPage();
myWP->setForwardUnsupportedContent(true);
myWP->setNetworkAccessManager(m_network);
ui->myWebView->setPage(myWP);

if(q!=true) {
    settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();

    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::OfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::OfflineStorageDatabaseEnabled,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanCloseWindows,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled,true);

    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavaEnabled,false);//Disable java
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled,true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);


    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DnsPrefetchEnabled, true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageDatabaseEnabled, true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AcceleratedCompositingEnabled, true);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanAccessClipboard, false);
    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::ScrollAnimatorEnabled, true);

    settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds, false);

    settings->setOfflineWebApplicationCachePath(QString(localStorage+"/appcache"));
    settings->enablePersistentStorage(QString(localStorage+"/persistent"));
    settings->setOfflineStoragePath(QString(localStorage+"/offlinestorage"));
    settings->setLocalStoragePath(QString(localStorage+"/storage"));
    settings->setIconDatabasePath(QString(localStorage+"/icons"));

    settings->setMaximumPagesInCache(99999);
    settings->setObjectCacheCapacities(0,99999,99999);

    settings->setOfflineWebApplicationCacheQuota(5*1024*1024);
    settings->setOfflineStorageDefaultQuota(5*1024*1024);
}
connect(ui->myWebView->page(), SIGNAL(downloadRequested(QNetworkRequest)), this, SLOT(Download(QNetworkRequest)));
connect(ui->myWebView->page(), SIGNAL(unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(unsupportedToDownload(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(ui->myWebView->page(), SIGNAL(printRequested(QWebFrame*)), this, SLOT(printFrame(QWebFrame*)));
```

Comment: Qt and Chrome both use [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) as the underlying code engine. That might explain the similar behavior.

Comment: the rendering code is the same, not requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem:

network.h

```
#ifndef NETWORK_H
#define NETWORK_H

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class netWork : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    virtual QNetworkReply *createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData = 0);

public:
    explicit netWork(QObject *parent = 0);
};

#endif // NETWORK_H
```

---

network.cpp

```
#include "network.h"
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>

netWork::netWork(QObject *parent) :
    QNetworkAccessManager(parent)
{
}

QNetworkReply * netWork::createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData){
    if(request.rawHeader("x-fixed-req")=="1") {//prevent infinite loop
        return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, request, outgoingData);
    }
    const QList<QByteArray>a = request.rawHeaderList();

    int j = a.length();
    int i=0;

    QNetworkRequest req(request.url());
    for(;i<j;++i){
        req.setRawHeader(a[i], request.rawHeader(a[i]));
    }
    req.setRawHeader("x-fixed-req", "1");

    QNetworkReply *p;
    if(op==PostOperation || op==PutOperation) {
        const QByteArray data = outgoingData->readAll();

        if(op==PostOperation) {
            p = this->post(req, data);
        } else {
            p = this->put(req, data);
        }
    } else if(op==DeleteOperation) {
        p = this->deleteResource(req);
    } else if(op==HeadOperation) {
        p = this->head(req);
    } else {
        p = this->get(req);
    }

    return p;
}
```

---

MainWindow.cpp (or something)

```
#include "network.h";

bool firstExec = false;
QNetworkCookieJar *cookieJar;

QNetworkDiskCache *m_cache;
netWork *m_network = new netWork; //custom networkaccessmanager

...

if(firstExec==false){
    firstExec = true;
    cookieJar = new QNetworkCookieJar;

    m_cache = new QNetworkDiskCache();
    m_cache->setCacheDirectory( QString("c:\\data") );

    m_network->setCache( m_cache );
    m_network->setCookieJar( cookieJar );

}

[QWEBVIEW]->setNetworkAccessManager( m_network );
```

> Note: To use cookies and cache, use the functions *QNetworkAccessManager::setCookieJar* and *QNetworkAccessManager::setCache*

Comment: You apparently used your own QNetworkAccessManager. I assume 'outerNetwork' is another QNetworkAccessManager. How did you manage to use them both for the same page? I ask because I'm kind of having the same problem. QtWebkit does not resend post requests for previously failed ones.

Comment: Forgive me, `outerNetwork` is a "global variable" receiving something like this: `QNetworkAccessManager *outerNetWork;`. I update my answer!

Comment: @jotep I did an update of the code, now it supports all SIGNALS (QNetworkAccessManager).